# Why does the Ministerio use famous people?

Tags: the-ministry-of-time

Among the agents of the eponymous Ministry of Time on the show of the same name are such luminaries as [Maria Pita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Pita) and [Diego Velazquez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez). Perhaps there are even some among the focal characters: I might not be too up to date on history, so I don't know whether Amelia is a real person, but as the first woman to go to college in Spain presumably she is also important to history. We've seen that the Ministerio's agents are put in some degree of risk, something that is brought most into focus in the episode where the aforementioned historical figures contract a deadly illness. But really, those people could have died in the missions they were sent on, and this seems rather ill-advised.

Thus, when a rather large portion of the Ministerio's work seems to be preventing the untimely death of famous figures from Spain's past, why are they using these self-same individuals to staff their dangerous missions?

Comment: I wouldn't know to answer your question, but as a bonus, Amelia Folch isn't a real person, but she's based on real persons from the XIX century. Her character is set in the same time period as the first women who started their university studies in Barcelona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a good in-universe explanation. Out-of-universe, using the famous people makes the show interesting.